# Creating a list based on column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df`

```
>>df
   LED  CFL  Incan  Hall  Reading
0  3    2    1      100   150
1  2    3    1      150   100
2  0    1    3      200   150
3  1    2    4      300   250
4  3    3    1      170   100
```

I want to create two more column which contain `lists`, one for `"Hall"` and another for `"Reading"`

```
>>df_output
   LED  CFL  Incan  Hall  Reading Hall_List Reading_List
0  3    2    1      100   150     [0,2,0]   [2,0,0]
1  2    3    1      150   100     [0,3,0]   [2,0,0]
2  0    1    3      200   150     [0,1,0]   [0,0,2]
3  1    2    4      300   250     [0,2,0]   [1,0,0]
4  3    3    1      100   100     [0,2,0]   [2,0,0]
```

Each value within the list is populated as follows:

```
cfl_rating = 50
led_rating = 100
incan_rating = 25
```

For the `Hall_List`:

The preference is CFL > LED > Incan. And only one of them will be used (either CFL or LED or Incan).

We first check if `CFL != 0` , if `True` then we calculate `min(ceil(Hall/CFL_rating),CFL)`. For `index=0` this evaluates to 2. Hence we have [0,2,0] whereas for `index=2` we have [0,1,0].

Similarly for `Reading_List`, the preference is LED > Incan > CFL.
For `index=2`, we have `LED == 0`, so we calculate `min(ceil(Reading/Incan_rating),Incan)` and hence Reading_List is `[0,0,2]`

**My question is:**
Is there a *"pandas/pythony-way"* of doing this? I am currently iterating through each row, and using if-elif-else conditions to assign values.

My code snippet looks like this:

```
#Hall_List
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    Hall = []
    if (df['CFL'].iloc[i] != 0):
        Hall.append(0)
        Hall.append(min((math.ceil(df['Hall'].iloc[i]/cfl_rating)),df['CFL'].iloc[i]))
        Hall.append(0)

    elif (df['LED'].iloc[i] != 0):
        Hall.append(min((math.ceil(df['Hall'].iloc[i]/led_rating)),df['LED'].iloc[i]))
        Hall.append(0)
        Hall.append(0)

    else:
        Hall.append(0)
        Hall.append(0)
        Hall.append(min((math.ceil(df['Hall'].iloc[i]/incan_rating)),df['Incan'].iloc[i]))

    df['Hall_List'].iloc[i] = Hall
```

This is really slow and definitely feels like a bad way to code this.

Answer (score 0):

I shorten your formula for simplicity sake but you should use df.apply(axis=1)

this take every row and return and ndarray, then you can apply whatever function you want such has :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 1, 100, 150], [2, 3, 1, 150, 100]], columns=['LED', 'CFL', 'Incan', 'Hall', 'Reading'])

def create_list(ndarray):
    if ndarray[1] != 0:
        result = [0, ndarray[1], 0]
    else:
        result = [ndarray[2], 0, 0]
    return result

df['Hall_List'] = df.apply(lambda x: create_list(x), axis=1)
```

just change the function to whatever you like here.

```
In[49]: df
Out[49]: 
   LED  CFL  Incan  Hall  Reading  Hall_List
0    3    2      1   100      150  [0, 2, 0]
1    2    3      1   150      100  [0, 3, 0]
```

hope this helps